# Does Migrating DB from On-Prem to Cloud Break OLEDB Connections?

Tags: sql, excel, oledb

Had trouble querying Google for answers to this question.

My IT team informed me tonight that they're moving forward with a migration to the cloud; they temporarily turned off the on-prem db during this process which broke some reporting and caused instant panic (people working off hours).

After the migration though, the engineer informed IT that they *would not* have to reenable the on-prem database as everything should smoothly work as is. We're skeptical.

Already, I've tried connecting to the DB from various applications targeting the DB (not sure how these connection strings are established, most are C# apps). These connections failed. This also leads me to believe that OLEDB connections, of which various excel reports depend, will break.

During this migration, will we need to hunt down each of these reports and reconfigure all of the OLEDB connections?

Forgive me as this is likely a stupid question. I just keep getting hums and hahs that if the DNS work, other connection strings won't be broken, but I'm skeptical as I doubt many if any apps/reports connect over DNS.

EDIT: Also tested an Excel file that grabs data; no dice on that. So guessing that's my answer.

And there we have it: Checked the connection string on one such report: [image]

Comment: _Already, I've tried connecting to the DB from various applications targeting the DB_ and what was the result?

Comment: Failed connection; so for apps that's the case; not sure if that's a server side config though (like a whitelisting problem) or if it's a problem with the connection string in the apps themselves.

Comment: I suggest you post the error message text in the question, and also send it to your IT people

Comment: _I doubt many if any apps/reports connect over DNS._ Everything connects over DNS. DNS is the service that turns a name into an IP address. This way you can have the same SQL Server name but now behind the scenes it points at a different IP address (which is a different SQL Server)

Comment: What about if the IP is say, hardcoded? Rather than given a domain name?

Comment: I only know one case where an application points direct to an IP for sure; our SQL Server Management Studio points to a static 10.X.X.X ip rather than a domain name.

Comment: If you're using IP's in your connection strings instead of names, yes you'll _probably_ have to change that. Generally you avoid ever using IP's for that reason. Luckily SQL Server Management studio is not really and end user tool and generally users have enough technical ability to know how to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume this is IaaS (they just moved the DB to a VM in the cloud), not PaaS (actually using Azure SQL, the cloud native SQL Server). You don't supply enough info to be sure.

You need two things to connect

*A. Network connectivity*

If the team has done this right, they have opened required ports, esnured there is network connectivity, and used DNS to ensure that whatever SQL Server name you use now points at the new SQL Server

*B. Authentication*

Again,  then as long as they migrated all SQL and windows logins, and ensured the VM was connected to the domain, everything should work

*In summary*

It's *possible* you don't need to change anything in your connect string, since the same server name works, and the same login works. You need to test everything as soon as you can since there are a lot of things that can go wrong

It's certainly strange that they would make this huge change and give you no notice

Comment: IT gave notice a week ago that they were migrating, and the migration should not be permanent, should have time to resolve, but they've turned off the original DB and at the recommendation of the engineer performing the migration, at least until they respond to my testing, intend to keep it off as far as I can see. I'm not even sure the original DB had DNS properly configured (i'm unaware of the domain name used if there is one) - but good to know that if network connectivity is performed right this could work. The AD it uses is local and not yet migrated - which I'm guessing will be an issue.

Comment: As long as the VM that the SQL Server is on can register itself into AD, you don't need to migrate it. This would be one of the first things they sorted out even before installing SQL Server. All this is conjecture at this point.